# App built in release mode using Xcode 11 getting crashed in iOS 11.3 while launching

Tags: crash, release, xcode11, ios11.3

I have built my application in Xcode 11 and it is launching in all iOS version from 10 to 13.1 under debug mode. But in iOS 11.3 under release mode(After archiving), my app is getting crashed when launching it. I am not able to see any crash log to get the reason for crashing. Except iOS 11.3 it is launching successfully in all other iOS version

I tried all other suggestions like disabling optimisation for release mode but no luck. If someone has come across the same issue please help me in resolving this issue

On checking the console logs, i see the below error

Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib no suitable image found